Coding comparisons and interactions with the R package marginaleffects
I am starting to learn how to use the R package marginaleffects and would appreciate help with some specific applications.
For illustration, let's use a dataset from the afex package. The variable phase is a factor with three levels: "fup", "post", and "pre". The variable age is continuous. Below is a model fit using lme4:
library(afex); library(lme4); library(phia)
data(obk.long, package = "afex")
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
fm <- lmer(value ~ phase * age + (1|id), data = obk.long)

I would like to replicate the following seven comparisons and interactions using marginaleffects:

Contrast between the first two levels ("fup" vs. "post") of the factor phase
In phia, this is done with:
testInteractions(fm, custom = list(phase = c(-1, 1, 0)), adjustment = "none")


Contrast between the first two levels of phase, with age fixed at 5.5
In phia:
testInteractions(fm, custom = list(phase = c(-1, 1, 0)), covariates = c(age = 5.5), adjustment = "none")


Slope of age (averaged across all levels of phase)
In phia:
testInteractions(fm, pairwise = NULL, slope = "age", adjustment = "none")


Slope difference in age between the first two levels ("fup" vs. "post") of phase
In phia:
testInteractions(fm, custom = list(phase = c(-1, 1, 0)), slope = "age", adjustment = "none")


Composite contrast among the three levels of phase (e.g., "fup" - "pre" and "post" - "pre")
In phia:
testFactors(fm, levels = testFactors(fm, levels = list(phase = rbind(diag(2), c(-1,-1)))))


Composite slope comparisons among the three levels of phase (e.g., slope differences for "fup" vs. "pre" and "post" vs. "pre")
In phia:
testFactors(fm, levels = testFactors(fm, levels = list(phase = rbind(diag(2), c(-1,-1)))), slope = "age")


Composite contrasts among the three levels of phase at a fixed age (e.g., "fup" - "pre" and "post" - "pre" at age = 5.5)
In phia:
testFactors(fm, levels = testFactors(fm, levels = list(phase = rbind(diag(2), c(-1,-1)))), covariates = c(age = 5.5))



My question is: how can I code these seven effects using the marginaleffects package?

Sorry, I don't know what you exactly mean by "composite contrasts", and I'm not familiar with the phia package. Here are replications of your first 4 examples. Hopefully that helps get you started.
library(afex); library(lme4); library(phia)
data(obk.long, package = "afex")
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
fm <- lmer(value ~ phase * age + (1|id), data = obk.long)

# 1: many options
testInteractions(fm, custom = list(phase = c(-1, 1, 0)), adjustment = "none")
hypotheses(fm, hypothesis = "phase2 - phase1 = 0")
hypotheses(fm, hypothesis = "b3 - b2 = 0")
hypotheses(fm, hypothesis = c(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
comparisons(fm, variables = "phase", newdata = datagrid(age = 0))

# 2
testInteractions(fm, custom = list(phase = c(-1, 1, 0)), covariates = c(age = 5.5), adjustment = "none")
comparisons(fm, variables = "phase", newdata = datagrid(age = 5.5))

# 3
testInteractions(fm, pairwise = NULL, slope = "age", adjustment = "none")
avg_slopes(fm, variables = "age")

# 4
testInteractions(fm, custom = list(phase = c(-1, 1, 0)), slope = "age", adjustment = "none")
avg_slopes(fm, variables = "age", by = "phase", hypothesis = "pairwise")

Edit:
I'm sorry, I can't figure out what phia is doing exactly. The syntax does not look transparent to me, and I don't have the time to dive in the documentation.
But note that you can apply multcomp package functions to marginaleffects objects. Perhaps you'll find what you need in there.
For example, here we look at the two contrasts: fup-pre=0 and post-pre=0, holding age=5.5, and then we conduct a global chi-squared test:
library(multcomp)

cmp <- comparisons(fm, 
    variables = list("phase" = "reference"), 
    newdata = datagrid(age = 5.5))

glht(cmp) |> summary(test = Chisqtest())
> 
>    General Linear Hypotheses
> 
> Linear Hypotheses:
>                 Estimate
> fup - pre == 0    1.8528
> post - pre == 0   0.8732
> 
> Global Test:
>   Chisq DF Pr(>Chisq)
> 1 29.29  2  4.359e-07


Thanks so much, @Vincent! By "composite contrasts," I’m referring to a null hypothesis that involves multiple effects simultaneously. For example, in #5, the null hypothesis for the three factor levels would be $H_0$: fup - pre = 0 and post - pre = 0. Does that make sense?

For #2, how can I obtain the contrast between post and pre at age of 5.5?

For #2, it is already printed.

I posted a hint but no definitive answer for the rest. Unfortunately, I won't have time to look at this further. Good luck.
